# Notifee - Execution failed for task ':notifee_react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I install Notifee package using yarn,

```
yarn add @notifee/react-native
```

After I run it,

```
yarn start
yarn run android
```

Throws an error like this,

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':notifee_react-native:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

I'm struggling to implement notifications in my React Native project. Really appreciate it if somebody could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As in v 6.0.0 added Android 13 support the compiledSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion should be changed to 33.

In your project `android/build.gradle` change,

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33
```

More reference,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxzi8Ug9NUA&ab_channel=CodewithMishen

Comment: Worked well for me on v.7.1.0, react-native 0.70.6

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone doesn't want to change the compileSdkVersion (maybe because other library will have compileDebugJavaWithJavac error) then they can try:

```
npm install --save @notifee/react-native@5.7.0
```

and keep the compileSdkVersion the same as before

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `allprojects` area of your `android/buld.gradle` file.

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210